# How to reshape an Array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have a 3D array of bytes in c# which I have read from a bitmap:

```
byte[w, h, 3]
```

What is the easiest and more performance-friendly way of reshaping this array into 2D (linear) form?

```
byte[w*h, 3]
```

In other words I want to keep number of channels (features) but in a linear shape (rather than a square shape)

Let me try to illustrate input and desired output:

input:

```
|(r1,g1,b1)    (r2,g2,b2)    (r3,g3,b3)|
|(r4,g4,b4)    (r5,g5,b5)    (r6,g6,b6)|
|(r7,g7,b7)    (r8,g8,b8)    (r9,g9,b9)|
```

note that arr[0, 0, 0] = r1, arr[0, 0, 1] = g1, arr[0, 0, 2] = b1, etc..

and output:

```
|(r1,g1,b1)    (r2,g2,b2)    (r3,g3,b3)    (r4,g4,b4)    (r5,g5,b5)    (r6,g6,b6) ...|
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work fine, because the array is *already in the right shape in memory*:

```
var a = new byte[2,  2, 2] { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
var b = new byte[2 * 2, 2];

//sizeof(byte) is obviously 1 here, but I put it there for documentation
Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.Length * sizeof(byte));
```

---

For those interested: As for what to do if you really want to *transpose* a 2D array into 1D:

```
byte[,] a = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6},
};
var b = new byte[a.GetLength(1) * a.GetLength(0)]; //Transpose

const int R_STRIDE1 = 8; //Tune this for your CPU
const int C_STRIDE1 = 8; //Tune this for your CPU

//You should hoist the calls to GetLength() out of the loop unlike what I do here
for (int r1 = 0; r1 < a.GetLength(0); r1 += R_STRIDE1)
for (int c1 = 0; c1 < a.GetLength(1); c1 += C_STRIDE1)
    for (int r2 = 0; r2 < R_STRIDE1; r2++)
    for (int c2 = 0; c2 < C_STRIDE1; c2++)
    {
        var r = r1 + r2;
        var c = c1 + c2;
        if (r < a.GetLength(0) && c < a.GetLength(1))
            b[c * a.GetLength(0) + r] = a[r, c];
    }
```

This should take advantage of caching in the CPU. I have **only** performed limited testing on this -- it could still be slow. Try tweaking it if it is.
You can (somewhat non-trivially) extend this to a 3D array.

Comment: Phew, I'm not sure whether you could get issues with Memory layout. Does the spec guarantee arrays are stored in sequentially mapped memory?

Comment: @Johannes: [They're in row-major order](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0c00d9af-4c10-4451-b7eb-972de0944ff8), but I think column-major would also work. You don't care about platform-specific padding because `BlockCopy` should take care of it anyway.

Comment: @Mehrdad, so does it mean I will get this in the result?: [1st-row 1st layer] [2nd-row 1st layer] ... [1st-row 2nd layer] [2nd-row 2nd layer]... ?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Good to know, Nevr worked with BlockCopy but happy it does handle that.

Comment: @valipour: Depends on what you mean by "row". In the example of `arr[a, b, c]`, *`c`* is the row, not `a`. And in that case, you'd go through the row before going through the next column.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Please see my new notes in the question

Comment: @valipour: WHOOPS my bad -- that was a typo; of course `b` is the row. Let me rephrase it: the *smallest* stride happens when you increment `c`. I think my answer does what you're expecting (try it!), but I think I misunderstood what you wrote in your comment -- I read "layer" as "column", so I thought it doesn't do what you expected; however, it does.

Comment: Is there a way *not* to copy the array?

Answer (score 3):

`Buffer.BlockCopy` will do it. At least, it works in this simple test.

```
byte[, ,] src = new byte[10, 10, 3];
byte[,] dest = new byte[100, 3];

List<byte> srcList = new List<byte>();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
        {
            byte b = (byte)rnd.Next();
            src[i, j, k] = b;
            srcList.Add(b);
        }
    }
}

Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dest, 0, 300);

List<byte> destList = new List<byte>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        destList.Add(dest[i, j]);
    }
}

// See if they're in the same order
for (int i = 0; i < srcList.Count; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,3:N0} - {1,3:N0}", srcList[i], destList[i]);
    if (srcList[i] != destList[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
    }
}
```

That said, I wouldn't use `Buffer.BlockCopy` in this way unless I was *absolutely sure* that there weren't odd cases with padding issues, etc. And although `Buffer.BlockCopy` is certainly faster than the equivalent explicit loop, it shouldn't materially affect the runtime of your program. Unless you're doing this conversion inside a piece of code that's called very, very often ... in which case you have bigger problems.

I would suggest writing the explicit loop.

Comment: Why wouldn't `BlockCopy` take care of padding issues? The padding issues should be transparent to the programmer, so it's the *responsibility* of `BlockCopy` to keep it that way. (Think about it: Otherwise, it would corrupt your memory!) There's **no reason** to avoid `BlockCopy` whatsoever.

Comment: For others reading this answer, take note that the fourth parameter to Buffer.BlockCopy is the number of **bytes** to copy not the length or number of elements to copy. In this example since we are copying bytes the numbers happen to be the same but if your buffer was another data type like float, do not forget to multiply by sizeof(float) to copy the correct number of elements. i.e. Buffer.BlockCopy(srcFloatArray, 0, destFloatArray, 0, sizeof(float) * 300);

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might want to use [System.Numerics.Tensors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Tensors/):

It makes reshaping very easy:

```
using System.Numerics.Tensors;
..
var src = new byte[3, w, h]
var dst = ArrayTensorExtensions
    .ToTensor(src)
    .Reshape(new[] { 3, w * h });
```