# Fill 3D array from list{int, int, int} in loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, int

I have  a `list{int a,int b,int c}` that holds data like

```
a  b  c
12 23 45
24 45 34
44 56 77
12 34 11
98 35 33
...
```

I want to have that data in 3 arrays 
so if I have 3 separated arrays I would do

```
int[] a = new int[lst.Count];
int[] b = new int[lst.Count];
int[] c = new int[lst.Count]; 
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) 
{
    a[i] = lst[i].a;
    b[i] = lst[i].b;
    c[i] = lst[i].c;
}
```

Now how to copy `list{int, int, int}` to 3d array?

```
int size = lst.Count;
int[, ,] array_t = new int[size , size , size ];
```

Comment: Why do you want to copy these values in 3D array? What would be the value hold by the "coordinates" [a, b, c] ?

Comment: What kind of `List<int,int,int>`? It's not clear to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reshape an Array in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522729/how-to-reshape-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DannyVarod That doesn't seem to be what OP's trying to do here.

Comment: @p.s.w.g This seems to be a private case of reshaping, where instead of one array of the length A*3, he/she has 3 arrays of length A. Other than that, of course, there is the problem of the 3D output matrix, where the result should be 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `int[,,]` is a 3-dimensional array, but it seems you're only dealing with 2-dimensional data, so an `int[,]` will be fine:

```
int[,] array_t = new int[lst.Count,3];
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) 
{
    array_t[i,0] = a[i];
    array_t[i,1] = b[i];
    array_t[i,2] = c[i];
}
```

Or skip the intermediate arrays:

```
int[,] array_t = new int[lst.Count,3];
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) 
{
    array_t[i,0] = lst[i].a;
    array_t[i,1] = lst[i].b;
    array_t[i,2] = lst[i].c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly (which I'm not sure), you seem to want to have a 3d array representing points at certain coordinates contained in your list. If it is what you want to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
    array_t[lst[i].a, lst[i].b, lst[i].c] = 1;
```

the rest of your array would be filled with zeros.