# Writing an efficient code for row-wise reshaping of multi-dimentsional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, reshape

I am converting my matlab code to C-code. I need to write a function for "reshaping" multi-dimensional array similar to "`reshape" function in matlab` who does it in "`row-wise`" manner.

Though I can write myself, I am cencerned that my method would be very inefficient, given I am not an expert C/C++ programmer. So, I am wondering if `someone already have some efficient code` and would be kind enugh to share.

I am looking for something **similar to what has been done in Armadillo library (C++ library)**.

```
.reshape(n_rows, n_cols, dim=0)   // For column-wise reshaping
.reshape(n_rows, n_cols, dim=1)   // For row-wise reshaping
```

Does anyone know **some lib in C doing similar**?

Usually `in Matlab I do the following operation` to convert `my 3D array and 4D array to equivalent 1D array` in row-wise manner.

```
%Creating y_exp_1D_NoReg: 1D equivelent of 3D data
Temp = reshape(y_exp_3D,[sizeH*sizeV, LenTE]);
yexp1D_1 = (reshape(Temp',[sizeH*sizeV*LenTE, 1]));  



%Creating y_exp_1D_NoReg: 1D equivelent of 4D data
Temp = reshape(y_exp_4D,[sizeZ*sizeH*sizeV,LenTE]);
yexp1D_2 = (reshape(Temp',[sizeZ*sizeH*sizeV*LenTE, 1]));
```

Also, for my C code, I have been using following libraries: `Lapack`, `Blas`, `TAUCS`

I could find an example here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522729/how-to-reshape-an-array-in-c-sharp); but this is in C# and hence not usable for me.

Comment: Use the library, trust me. It will save you time and problems. This doesn't seem to be a particularily hard task to do, but could you be more detailed on where do you get the inputs from?

Comment: If you are converting to C, what does C++ have to do with this? (FYI: C != C++)

Comment: @iharob Since Armadillo is written in C++, I am wondering if some library does it in C.

Comment: @crashmstr I also put C++ as I refer to armadillo in my question which is a library in C++. None the less, C++ tag has been removed.

Comment: @GarimaSingh I have no Idea, I was recommending to use the library because it would avoid a lot of unnecessary work, if you want c only you should remove the c++ tag, and try to explain more on how are you going to pass input to the c program and I can try to help you.

Comment: If you are doing this for fun and learning, then feel free to reinvent the wheel.