# FORTRAN 77 3 dimensional array initialization equivalent to C#

Tags: c#, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to code a three dimensional array declared and initialized in FORTRAN 77 to its equivalent in C#.

After doing some research, I discovered that FORTRAN 77 follows column major approach. Still I am not able to visualize how I can represent the 3 dimensional array initialized in FORTRAN 77 in C#. Here is the FORTRAN 77 code that declares and initializes a 3 dimensional array:

```
real*4 temperature_factors(2,6,9)/
     c  .000,.054, .055,.070, .071,.085, .086,.105, .106,.200,
     c  -1.0,-1.0,
     c  -1.0,-1.0, -1.0,-1.0, .125,.164, .165,.204, .205,.404,
     c  .405,.604,
     c  0.0,12.0, 12.1,35.4, 35.5,55.4, 55.5,150.4, 150.5,250.4,
     c  250.5,500.4,
     c  0.0,54.0, 55.0,154.0, 155.0,254.0, 255.0,354.0, 355.0,424.0,
     c  425.0,604.0,
     c  0.0,4.4, 4.5,9.4, 9.5,12.4, 12.5,15.4, 15.5,30.4,
     c  30.5,50.4,
     c  .000,.035, .036,.75, .76,.185, -1.,  -1.,  -1., -1.,
     c   -1., -1.,
     c   -1., -1.,  -1., -1., -1., -1.,.186,.304, .305,.604,
     c  .605,1.004,
     c  -1.0,10.0, -1.0,-1.0, -1.0,-1.0, -1.0,-1.0, -1.,-1.0,
     c  -1.0,10.0,
     c  .000,.053, .054,.100, .101,.360, .361,.649, .650,1.249,
     c  1.250,2.049/
```

My initial attempt to represent the above in C#:

```
double[, ,] temperature_factors = new double[2, 6, 9]
            {
                {
                    {0.000, 0.054,  0.055,  0.070,  0.071,  0.085,  0.086,  0.105,  0.106,},
                    {0.200, -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   0.125,  0.164},
                    {0.165, 0.204,  0.205,  0.404,  0.405,  0.604,  0.0,    12.0,   12.1},
                    {35.4,  35.5,   55.4,   55.5,   150.4,  150.5,  250.4,  250.5,  500.4},
                    {0.0,   54.0,   55.0,   154.0,  155.0,  254.0,  255.0,  354.0,  355.0},
                    {424.0, 425.0,  604.0,  0.0,    4.4,    4.5,    9.4,    9.5,    12.4}
                },

                {
                    {12.5,  15.4,   15.5,   30.4,   30.5,   50.4,   0.000,  0.035,  0.036},
                    {0.75,  0.76,   0.185,  -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0},
                    {-1.0,  -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   0.186,  0.304,  0.305},
                    {0.604, 0.605,  1.004,  -1.0,   10.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0},
                    {-1.0,  -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0,   10.0,   0.000,  0.053,  0.054},
                    {0.100, 0.101,  0.360,  0.361,  0.649,  0.650,  1.249,  1.250,  2.049}
                }
            };
```

But obviously this is not correct. Can anyone please help me initialize the 3 dimensional array written in FORTRAN 77 to its equivalent in C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran arrays are column-major, so the literal values in the Fortran code are populated to `A` in the order `A(1,1,1), A(2,1,1), A(1,2,1), A(2,2,1), ..., A(1,6,9), A(2,6,9)` (where `A` means `temperature_factors`). On the other hand, C# arrays are row-major (according to this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Programming_languages_and_libraries) and a mini test (please see the bottom of this answer)), so I think we need to switch the order of indices to make use of the sequence of literal values directly. Specifically, we first create a 1D (temporary) array from the literal values as

```
double[] arr1 = new double[ 9 * 6 * 2 ]
    {
        .000,.054,  .055,.070,  .071,.085,   .086,.105,   .106,.200,    -1.0,-1.0,
        -1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,  .125,.164,   .165,.204,   .205,.404,    .405,.604,
        0.0,12.0,   12.1,35.4,  35.5,55.4,   55.5,150.4,  150.5,250.4,  250.5,500.4,
        0.0,54.0,   55.0,154.0, 155.0,254.0, 255.0,354.0, 355.0,424.0,  425.0,604.0,
        0.0,4.4,    4.5,9.4,    9.5,12.4,    12.5,15.4,   15.5,30.4,    30.5,50.4,
        .000,.035,  .036,.75,   .76,.185,    -1.0,-1.0,   -1.0,-1.0,    -1.0,-1.0,
        -1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,   .186,.304,   .305,.604,    .605,1.004,
        -1.0,10.0,  -1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,   -1.0,-1.0,   -1.0,-1.0,    -1.0,10.0,
        .000,.053,  .054,.100,  .101,.360,   .361,.649,   .650,1.249,    1.250,2.049
    };
```

and then copy elements one-by-one via loops (where the right-most index `k` should run fastest):

```
double [,,] arr3 = new double[ 9, 6, 2 ];

int ind = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    arr3[ i, j, k ] = arr1[ ind ];
    ind++;
}
```

or equivalently, copy a chunk of memory directly (according to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522729/how-to-reshape-an-array-in-c-sharp))

```
Buffer.BlockCopy( arr1, 0, arr3, 0, arr1.Length * sizeof(double) );
```

We can check the result by printing a few elements of `arr3`:

```
// using static System.Console;
WriteLine( arr3[ 0, 0, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3[ 0, 0, 1 ] );
WriteLine( arr3[ 0, 1, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3[ 0, 1, 1 ] );
WriteLine( "..." );
WriteLine( arr3[ 8, 4, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3[ 8, 4, 1 ] );
WriteLine( arr3[ 8, 5, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3[ 8, 5, 1 ] );
```

which gives

```
0         // A(1,1,1) in Fortran
0.054     // A(2,1,1)
0.055     // A(1,2,1)
0.07      // A(2,2,1)
...
0.65      // A(1,5,9)
1.249     // A(2,5,9)
1.25      // A(1,6,9)
2.049     // A(2,6,9)
```

---

To use the same order of indices as Fortran, it may also be useful to
create another 3D array with the index order reversed, such that:

```
double [,,] arr3_alt = new double[ 2, 6, 9 ];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
    arr3_alt[ i, j, k ] = arr3[ k, j, i ];
}

WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 0, 0, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 1, 0, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 0, 1, 0 ] );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 1, 1, 0 ] );
WriteLine( "..." );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 0, 4, 8 ] );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 1, 4, 8 ] );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 0, 5, 8 ] );
WriteLine( arr3_alt[ 1, 5, 8 ] );
```

---

This is a mini test that I tried to check the alignment of
array elements in memory:

```
    int[,] A = new int[2,3] { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
    int[]  B = new int[6];

    Buffer.BlockCopy( A, 0, B, 0, sizeof(int) * 6 );  // A=src, B=dest, 0=offset, count=in-bytes

    WriteLine( "B[0] = " + B[0] + " A[0,0] = " + A[0,0] );
    WriteLine( "B[1] = " + B[1] + " A[0,1] = " + A[0,1] );
    WriteLine( "B[2] = " + B[2] + " A[0,2] = " + A[0,2] );
    WriteLine( "B[3] = " + B[3] + " A[1,0] = " + A[1,0] );
    WriteLine( "B[4] = " + B[4] + " A[1,1] = " + A[1,1] );
    WriteLine( "B[5] = " + B[5] + " A[1,2] = " + A[1,2] );
```

which gives

```
B[0] = 1 A[0,0] = 1
B[1] = 2 A[0,1] = 2
B[2] = 3 A[0,2] = 3
B[3] = 4 A[1,0] = 4
B[4] = 5 A[1,1] = 5
B[5] = 6 A[1,2] = 6
```

Comment: A more direct way may be `double[,,] arr3 = new double[ 9, 6, 2 ] { {        {.000,.054},  {.055,.070}, ... {1.250,2.049} }};`, but adding many {} might be rather tedious??

Comment: Hmm, not sure I agree with this answer.  The Fortran array is `2*6*9` but the C# array is `9*6*2`.  Surely it should also be `2*6*9` ?

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure, but it seems from some test that the elements of A[ 2, 2 ] (in C#) are aligned in memory such that A[0,0] -> A[0,1] -> A[1,0] -> A[1,1] (on my Mac + homebrew + mono). So I assumed that a rectangular array in C# is contiguous row-wise, but hmm, please do correct it... (If totally wrong, I will delete the answer.)

Comment: And of course, I guess we can also declare A[2,6,9] and copy elements with transpose (so that the order of indices are the same between C# and Fortran).