# Loading multi-dimensional array dynamically

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code. It's roughly analogous in concept to the python `reshape` function. It successfully loads 1-dimensional data into a multi-dimensional array, the dimensions of which are not known until runtime. For example `{209,64,64,3}`. I have to iterate over the 1-dimensional data and create the correct indexes for each dimension of the array.

```
private void InitializeData()
{
  var imageData = ImageData.Load(txtFileName.Text); // one dimensional array
  var dimensions = txtDimensions.Text.Split(',').Select(d => int.Parse(d)).ToArray(); // e.g., {-1,64,64,3}
  int elements = 1;
  foreach (var dim in dimensions.Skip(1))
  {
    elements *= dim;
  }
  dimensions[0] = imageData.Length / elements; // {209,64,64,3}
  // create multipliers
  var multipliers = new int[dimensions.Length - 1];
  for (var dimension = 1; dimension < dimensions.Length; dimension++)
  {
    var multiplier = 1;
    for (var followingdimension = dimension; followingdimension < dimensions.Length; followingdimension++)
    {
      multiplier *= dimensions[followingdimension];
    }
    multipliers[dimension - 1] = multiplier;
  }
  // load data
  var dataArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), dimensions);
  var indexes = new int[dimensions.Length];
  for (var imageDataIndex = 0; imageDataIndex < imageData.Length; imageDataIndex++)
  {
    indexes[0] = imageDataIndex / multipliers[0];
    indexes[dimensions.Length - 1] = imageDataIndex % multipliers[multipliers.Length - 1];
    for (var multiplier = 1; multiplier < dimensions.Length - 1; multiplier++)
      indexes[multiplier] = (imageDataIndex / multipliers[multiplier]) % dimensions[multiplier];
    dataArray.SetValue(imageData[imageDataIndex], indexes);
  }
}
```

Is there a faster or more elegant way of doing this? I do realize those are two different things. I'll do bench-marking on the elegant suggestions, but I'd still like to see them. Because this is just too ugly to look at and was too painful to write to be the best way.

**Note (Please)**

The data may not always be image data, so I am not looking for bitmap operations. That just happens here but it's not necessarily a typical case. And, my goal is not to get a bitmap, but an array.

Comment: How are you using `dataArray` after you create it? What code are you using to access its elements?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, Hi. It will become involved in matrix operations. Which was going to be a seperate query, how to vectorize array operations in c#. I haven't written that code yet. In math if you have two matrices you can do A * B or A - 4, etc. I'm assuming that in c# a matrix is an n-dimensional regular array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial answer thanks to [How to reshape an Array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522729/how-to-reshape-an-array-in-c-sharp/6522822#6522822)

The code can be replaced with just this:

```
  var imageData = ImageData.Load(txtFileName.Text); // one dimensional array
  // e.g., {209,64,64,3}
  var dimensions = txtDimensions.Text.Split(',').Select(d => int.Parse(d)).ToArray();
  int elements = 1;
  foreach (var dim in dimensions.Skip(1))
  {
    elements *= dim;
  }
  dimensions[0] = imageData.Length / elements;
  // load data
  var dataArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), dimensions);
  Buffer.BlockCopy(imageData, 0, dataArray, 0, imageData.Length * sizeof(int));
```

I would be surprised if there's a faster way to do the actual load then `Buffer.BlockCopy`, or a simpler one. It turns out whatever dimensional form your original data is in, `BlockCopy` handles it as long as you can specify your target dimensions as part of a target array.

I'll keep looking for ways to further refine the rest of the original code.